# regex expression for conclusion

Tags: regex, pdf, numbers

I want to create the regex function that goes over the whole text only by the number of Headings and then tell the python that stops when there is no number.
Can anyone help me with this?
**This is the text:**
1 Introduction
Aggregate measures such as income per capita or Gini index have serious limitations to show a
comprehensive picture of an economy. They cannot describe which individuals or households
and how much of them are better or worse off following booms and busts, and crises an
recoveries (Berman 2018a). For a certain income growth and distribution of income, we can
consider cases that major parts of people are beneficiaries, or cases that most of them are losers
and lots of intermediate cases (see Table 1 for a toy example). Absolute intragenerational
income mobility, defined as the fraction of households whose real income per capita is higher
at the end of a period compared to the beginning of that period, can answer to this question.
Relative measures of mobility show the percent better off in income rank instead of absolute income. Intergenerational mobility studies percent of children better off compared to
their parents. Relative mobilities are studied for a long time and for different countries. See for example Corak (2020) and Lee and Solon (2009) for relative intergenerational mobility and Silvia et al. (2013) and Parrado (2005) for relative intragenerational mobility. Moreover, prior to Chetty et al. (2017), the absolute mobility is documented in the literature in terms other than the income such as occupational status (Arrow et al. 2018) and educational attainment (Duncan and Murnane 2011). Chetty et al. (2017) for the first time show the absolute income mobility trend.

2 Mobility
We need to track the households or individuals’ income over the time to estimate the absolute intragenerational income mobility. Panel data surveys such as PSID1 or administrative
data sets such federal income tax records used in Chetty et al. (2014) in the United States.

I want to create pattern that python find for me the content of all parts by the number of each heading. so which code I can write for regex? so for instance, I want to cover the part of introduction and mobility by writing the codes for that.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "only by the number of Headings".  You don't really specify what type of text you're processing.  But a simple example of a regex filter that will match anything until it hits a number is:

    [^0-9]*

Comment: the point is that I am importing 150 pdf files which are articles and then with regex I want to tell python to read all text but stop after the conclusion and I do not want to consider the reference part of article. So, it means that I want to tell python to extract the parts that only has heading numbers and then stop. do u get me ?

Comment: Are you using a pdf library to parse the pdf docs?  if so, they usually give you access to the structure of the doc in a way that I would think would be more efficient than using regex over the whole text of the document.

Comment: really thanks for ur comment, but I have to solve it by regex. do u have any idea for that?

Comment: Not without seeing a sample of the text sorry.  You're not including any actionable information in your description of the problem.  To build a regex filter you need to know what patterns are present in the text that's being searched.  You'll need to add some examples to the question.

Comment: I added a part of pdf for you in my question to see what I mean. if you can help me to write the regex code I would be grateful. really thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^\d\n] [^\n]*
```

Explanation:

- Take everything as long as there is no line return: `[^\n]*`
- BUT that must start with a non-number: `^[^\d\n]` (I also filtered-out the line return)
- Notice that I put a whitespace between the two statements